How many dimensions is the MSE error function
let's say we have n data points($y_i$) and our model:
$$h(x) = \theta_1 x + \theta_2$$
then:
$$MSE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - h(x_i))^2$$
$$MSE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - (\theta_1 x_i + \theta_2))^2$$
my question si how many dimensions is the MSE, 3 dimensional? I don't get if the parameters are $\theta_1$ $\theta_2$ or $\theta_1$ $\theta_2$ and $x_i$

Notice that the $x_i$s are fixed and given ahead of time.

@whpowell96 thanks
